# Can you assign a WiX Property to CommonAppDataFolder?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I would like to set an overrideable property for a WiX property to the current location of CommonAppDataFolder.  So far I have tried the following:

```
<Property Id="GHOSTSCRIPT" Value="[CommonAppDataFolder]"/>
```

as well as

```
<Property Id="GHOSTSCRIPT" Value="CommonAppDataFolder"/>
```

Neither one resolves correctly.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use the SetProperty element instead.

Answer (score 2):

The Property element writes a row to the Windows Installer [Property table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The value column is type "text" not type "formatted" so the [PROPNAME] doesn't work.

The SetProperty element schedules a Property Custom Action (Type 51) in the needed sequence and it supports what you are trying to do.

[SetProperty Element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_setproperty.htm)

Comment: I tried that, and it does allow you to set the property, but it doesn't work for the "overrideable" requirement, since a type 51 action always overwrites any value that would be passed in from the command line.

Comment: You put a condition on the custom action to not fire when a value is passed in the commandline. ( i.e. set FOO=BAR Condition Not FOO)